# ReactJs Menu item relative to select

Tags: css, reactjs, select, menuitem

[image]

I am using select menuitem from material UI. I am able to position the dropdown at bottom left with help of the code inside select.

anchorOrigin: {
vertical: "bottom",
horizontal: "left"
},
getContentAnchorEl: null,

But the issue is when the webpage is scrolled MenuItems starts moving all over the page. But I want to place them below the select itself even in case of scroll of a page.

Comment: can you give some code that you tried ,a code pen will be more helpful

Comment: The problem is that I can't share it here

Comment: I found a similar question when a dropdown is opened and the window is scrolled it is not staying below the select.

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-leaf-ooko1)

Answer (score 1):

using `disableScrollLock:true` create modeless popup which allows user to scroll the container element when dropdown is open,however giving it `false` will create modal pop up for select and user will not allowed to scroll container element until focus from select is removed ,you just need to change one line in the link you shared here is the complete code

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const names = [
  "Oliver Hansen",
  "Van Henry",
  "April Tucker",
  "Ralph Hubbard",
  "Omar Alexander",
  "Carlos Abbott",
  "Miriam Wagner",
  "Bradley Wilkerson",
  "Virginia Andrews",
  "Kelly Snyder"
];

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
PaperProps: {
style: {
  maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
  width: 250
}
},
disableScrollLock: false
};

export default function App() {
 const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

 const handleChange = event => {
  setPersonName(event.target.value);
 };

  return (
   <div className="App" style={{ height: "1000px" }}>
     <FormControl>
       <Select
        labelId="demo-mutiple-name-label"
        id="demo-mutiple-name"
        multiple
        value={personName}
        onChange={handleChange}
        input={<Input />}
        MenuProps={MenuProps}
       >
        {names.map(name => (
          <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
            {name}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
     </FormControl>
    </div>
   );
   }
```

Comment: I can't disable the scroll bar

Comment: open the link you shared,goto app.js line 31,replace true with false,and scrollbar will disbale from container when menu is open

Comment: That is the issue bro. I have to show the scroll bar when dropdown is opened and position should stay at the same location

Comment: obvious not possible, you must have to block user from scrolling to make it stay with its anchor position or it will scroll along with window

Comment: you can try using native select in this case